# DNN scheduler runs successfully but no data is updated in database

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

Working on a website developed on DNN (website created by someone else).
Can see the Scheduler is running successfully in Scheduler History on website.
Scheduler function says it is writing XML files to Database but after running Scheduler 
the database is not updated.

Where can I find the connection string for the database?It is not specified in the schedulerproject.vb file . Where else can I find this? Any idea what might be the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to really depend on the actual scheduled job that you are running.

However, most database connections are in the `<connectionStrings>` section of the web.config per best practices.